# Why jquery .fail does not receive arguments firing error intentionally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use custom json encoded data after firing an error on server
(throwing error intentionally) under jquery ajax request.

I don´t understand what is wrong, because the header is right and the data arrives. But it seems that the exception arguments are not passed to the exception callback in javascript.

The php code

```
<?php

 if ( valid_input() )
 {
    ...      
 } 
 else // The validation goes wrong so, I have to return error
 {
   // Error code
   header('HTTP/1.1 500 Format does not match');
   header('Content-Type: application/json');    
   die(json_encode(array('message' => 'Bad format', 'code' =>1000)));
 }
?>
```

The javascript code

```
$("#uploadbutton").on('click',function(e)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://www.oneurl.com/upload.php",
        async:true,
        type:'post',
        data:formdata
    })
    .done(render_data)
    .fail(upload_error);
});

//
function render_data(params) {...}

function upload_error(jqxhr,textstatus,ex)
{
 alert("Error:-> ", ex.message);   
}
```

Response from server

```
Status Code: 500 Format does not match
Content-Type: application/json
Response: {"message":"Bad Format","code":1000}
```

But the alert is undefined instead Bad Format.
What is wrong ?¿

Comment: Fail will be triggered if the request really fails, like a 404 error or “unable to connect”. You custom 500 error will never trigger the fail function.

Comment: @muecas No, I have posted the headers... Please check it on localhost. If it had not been called, the alert neither. But is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` is stored as the `responseText` property of the `jqXHR` parameter. It comes back as a JSON string, so you'll need to `JSON.parse` it before you can directly access the properties.

```
function upload_error(jqxhr,textstatus,ex)
{
    var response = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
    alert("Error:-> ", response.message);   
}
```